# Is it correct to put "is" at the end of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> What an astonishing city Milano is

Is it correct to put the "is" at the end?

Comment: Yes - but it would *also* be "correct" to have the word ***is*** earlier. *What an astonishing city **is** Milano!*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i though i put the auxierly verb before the noun just in questions. "What is milano?", "what milano is a city in italy", is that correct please ?

Comment: @sarah Not in this case, since it's being considered as an exclamative sentence.

Comment: sarah: What @Ustanak said. The "normal" sequence in English is *subject - verb - object*, so *He doesn't realise what an astonishing city Milano is* is "standard". But you need to be careful about assuming *all and only* "questions" reverse the standard sequence, since it's also standard to ask *Do you realise what an astonishing city Milano is?* And for "exclamatory" or "poetic" contexts, it's *also* common to reverse the sequence there too (but there's nothing *wrong* with your usage above; it's just not the *only* valid form).

Comment: By the way, Milano has an English name: Milan.

Comment: @ColinFine I know, but I am writing to an Italian person form Milan, so it is better to use the Italian name

Comment: Do you intend it to be a full sentence or a part of a longer sentence? Is it a question or an exclamation? I would personally put the "is" at the end, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

This an exclamatory sentence so all it lacks is the "!".

Grammatically speaking, formal English requires exclamations to begin with either the word what or how.  But in everyday informal English you’ll find exclamations can begin with any word, as you’ll see in the examples of exclamatory sentences to follow.

But first, two more grammar rules you need to know about:

Rule Number One: If the noun in your sentence is plural, the correct choice is what, not how.

“What exceptional children these are!” is correct.
“How exceptional children these are!” is incorrect.

'What' is acceptable with singular nouns as well.
“What an exceptional child this is!” -http://www.k12reader.com/exclamatory-sentences-rock/

In addition I found:

What + a/an + (adjective) + noun + subject + verb
What a fool you are! (NOT What a fool are you!)
What a charming girl she is! (NOT What a charming girl is she!)
What a beautiful smile you have! (NOT What a beautiful smile have you!)

-http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/exclamatory-sentences-verb-patterns/

5. Exclamatory Sentence
   A sentence that expresses strong feelings or emotions is called an exclamatory sentence. These sentences express surprise, joy, sorrow, appreciation, love excitement, frustration, anger etc. An exclamatory sentence ends with exclamation mark.
   Examples
   What a beautiful flower it is!
   (the auto-editor won't let me paste additional links for this last example)

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: I added an explanation, but this is usually taught in second grade as a grammatical structure. I'll try to find additional sources.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put some references into your answer. We should be careful though to explain what we've found using our own words and tailoring the information to the question that was asked instead of copying and pasting too much.